# Transferring characters into spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a block of text in binary, and I need to transfer it to an excel spreadsheet such that each cell has only one digit.

[image: An Example]

I have a large amount of characters, more than 3000, and my task is made more complicated by the fact that some cells are already filled and I need to preserve their positions.

I've tried pasting *n* characters into *n* cells, but that didn't work.

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: Don't understand "block of text in binary" - is the text ASCII encoded with the resultant ASCII codes expressed in binary? Also unclear on what you mean by transferring to your excel spreadsheet. Your image may or may not be related to your input or your output. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @AJD Yes, exactly what you said. See the line of 1s and 0s? So basically, I have a large amount of text and I have to transfer the text to a spreadsheet such that each cell has only one character.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could show a short snippet of the input file (say as a hex listing) and what output you would like to have from that file. I guess there is no standard function in Excel to do this conversion, you will need to do some programming. Excel has a built-in programming language called VBA that might be used. If I had the problem, I would most probable transform the input file externally, say using Python, to a format excel might like better, say CSV.

Comment: @ghellquist `...1000110010111100101100101101100100000111100111011111110101100000110000111100101100101100000110110111110011000001101101110111111100111...` It'd be like this. The red part of the image is already filled with numbers, and I don't want them to change their positions. The white part has to be filled with the characters. I'm not very familiar with tech jargon, so layman speak, please?

Comment: Open the data in a separate Excel document, then copy and paste from there? You have not show what there is stopping this.

Comment: @Hannu The text is in Word.

Comment: Well then, select it, copy and paste in Excel, done. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Hannu Each character has to be in a separate cell.

Comment: You will have to write a VBS/VBA macro.  opening the file inside the macro so you can have more control over it. Read in the file 1 row at a time, and then use a for/next loop to set the individual cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the text into one cell. You might need to have a ' tick as start, otherwise excel might believe it is a number.

Extrakt one character at a time with =Mid(..) function. See example.

I tend to be lazy and put increasing numbers in a row, and using that as index. This allows me to simply copy the formula.

[image: Example]

Comment: I saw this just now. Will try soon and accept if it works.